# Where are all the Magento email templates located?

Tags: email, templates, magento

Magento seems to have lots of email templates to send a variety of different messages based on user activities: registration, password recovery, order, shipment, etc.

Where can I find all the email templates so I can customize them ALL and never miss one of them to avoid looking bad when the user sees a poorly worded default template?

Are they all located in one location / directory?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`app/locale/en_US/template/email/` is the default place/locale. You should not customize them in the filesystem, or if you do, plan on protecting & merging when you upgrade.

You can customize them (albeit somewhat wonkily) via System > Transactional Emails. In this area you select the base file for your locale and alter the content, which is then stored in the database.

Comment: Thanks! But this kind of sucks because I have to: 1) create 36 email templates from Magento default ones, 2) assign these created templates one by one to each of the 36 functionalities that use email templates which are scattered across all different panels in System -> Configuration........what were they thinking....

Comment: Wait a minute, I thought there's a locale directory inside each theme, such as the modern theme: /app/design/frontend/default/modern/locale/en_US.....So if I create email templates there in template/email, would they be used over the system default ones?

Comment: Sucks, it doesn't work that way.... email templates should by all means be considered part of the theme...

Comment: No, locale will contain an IDO-coded dir (for chosen locale) which contains a `translate.csv` file. This file is used to collect translations particular to a theme + locale setting. It should be trivial to get the email templates to use theming logic though... gets me thinking...

Comment: Where are the emails located that are created via system>transactional emails!?

Comment: @user1964129 - `core_email_template` table.

Answer (score 6):

for Magento 1.9.x.x

```
app/locale/lang_CODE/template/email
```

for Magento 2.x

```
app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a free plugin that lets you override the email templates:
https://github.com/yireo-magento1/Yireo_EmailOverride/

(**archive homepage in 2014:** https://web.archive.org/web/20140703022933/https://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/email-override)

This is where you place the overrides:

```
app/design/frontend/{PACKAGE}/{THEME}/locale/{LOCALE}/template/email
```

So if I was overriding this file:

```
app/locale/en_US/template/email/account_new.html
```

and if my package name is "package" and my theme is "default", I would place my override file here:

```
app/design/frontend/package/default/locale/en_US/template/email/account_new.html
```

Answer (score 0):

app/locale/`<Language>`/template/email/

Find all the templates with names.